# beautifulsoup returning data as None that includes <br> tag

Tags: python, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

I have a table data like this:

```
<table class="tablesorter" id="dea">
<thead>
<tr>
<th class="header ">Name</th>
<th class="header">City</th>
<th class="">Address</th>
<th class="">Phone Nos</th>
<th class="">Email</th>
<th class="">Fax</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

<tr class="info">
<td style="font:bold 12px Tahoma; color:#1f2c48;">Audi California</td>
<td>&nbsp;California&nbsp;</td>
<td align="left">
A?85, bay Area, Phase 1, <br>
California<br>
California
- 6554655
</td>
<td align="right">
<br>4747744747<br>108388383
</td>
<td align="center">
info<!-- >@_ -->@<!-- >@_ -->audiCal<!-- >@_ -->.<!-- >@_ -->net
</td>
<td align="right">
&nbsp;
</td>
</tr></tbody>
</table>
```

I am using beautifulsoup to parse this, but now I got into problem while fetching data from last four `<td>`. Whenever I read their values using `.string` property, I get `None` as value. I guess this is because they have `<br>` tags. I want last four `<td>` data that has address, phone no., email_id and fax. Instead of `.string` what should I use to get all those data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `.text` for getting the text.

Edit:

Another option may be getting every element using `.contents` and joining them as necessary.

Comment: Uisng .text works but it gives me <br>4747744747<br>108388383 as 4747744747108388383 and i want it to be 4747744747,108388383  :|

Answer (score 0):

Once you have a handle to `td` element you can use:

```
 td.findAll(text=True)
```

to get a list of text subelements of the `td` tag. Then you can `join` that list on `,`